# Laravel adding error messages to ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am trying to make a form to submit via ajax in laravel 5 and it works to a certain point.

This is my ajax/jQuery:

```
$('#RegisterSubmit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $('#RegisterForm');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/register_process',
                data: form.serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                timeout: 9000,

            });
            $('#RegisterForm')[0].reset();

    });
```

Everything works fine, the user can register and information is sent to database but when the user makes an error I want there to be a message saying that.ex: 'username field is empty'.

I managed to do that by using html like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class = "col" for = "username" >username:</label>
     <div class = "col">
        <input id = "username" class=" input {{ $errors->has('username') ? 'has-error' : '' }}" type = "username" name = "username" value="{{ Input::old('username') }}"></input><br>
        {!! $errors->first('username' , '<span style = "color:red">:message</span>') !!}
     </div>
    </div>
```

But now i can't use this anymore as I am sending data with ajax, what can I do to fix this ?

These is how I show messages:

```
public function StoreRegister()
{
    $messages = [
        'unique' => 'Acest :attribute deja exista',
        'min' => 'Câmpul :attribute trebuie sa conţina cel puţin :min caractere',
        'required' => 'Campul :attribute trebuie completat',
        'email' => 'Campul :attribute trebuie sa fie valid'
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),Register::$rules,$messages);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }

    Register::saveFormData(Input::except(array('_token')));
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Comment: i don't really underestand what you are saying, but laravel already gives me this error messages throught this line of code :" {!! $errors->first('username' , '<span style = "color:red">:message</span>') !!}" i just don't know how to put it in ajax.

Answer (score 5):

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/register_process',
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    timeout: 9000,
                    error: function(data){
                        if( data.status === 422 ) {
                          var errors = data.responseJSON;
                          errorHtml='<div class="errors"><ul>';
                          $.each( errors, function( key, value ) {
                               errorHtml += '<li>' + value[0] + '</li>';
                         });
                          errorHtml += '</ul></div>';
                          $( '#formerrors' ).html( errorHtml );

                    }
                 }
         });
```

When using validate during ajax ,laravel generates json reponse containing each error messages and status of that response is **422**.Do not forget to add a div 
for displaying errors.

```
<div id="formerrors"></div>
```

Comment: so are you saying that i should forget about laravel messages and create my own filters ?

Comment: @Urarii how did you get messages?

Comment: i edited first post, messages appear if i put {!! $errors->first('username' , '<span style = "color:red">:message</span>') !!} in html but i don't know how to do it on ajax.

Comment: After ajax function returns errors then you have to display them using jquery.just edit my answer to show how to display all error in one place but you can get every single error and insert them where you want it to be.

Comment: I do not know why it doesn't work, it seems very logical yet nothing happens.(i did not forget to add the div)

Comment: first of all be sure that errors really exist.try to debug or put console.log to every step and see what is wrong;

Comment: then there is problem with your server side implementation

Comment: in console it says: POST localhost/register_process 500 (Internal Server Error) PS:If i remove error(code you gave me) it works, and when i don't meet the cryterias,for example if i dont fill the username field the informations are not introduced in database,it is just that the messages won't show.

Comment: i used console.log(data); and this appeared:Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: you should read https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/showing-request-validation-errors-when-submitting-form-by-ajax and http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation